# How banks and other companies handle recurring tasks?

Tags: enterprise, scheduler

I'm curious how banks handle recurring tasks of their users. And if they have thousands of those tasks, for example paypal recurring payments, how does paypal handle them? What software they use? I dont think they use cron\quartz for such tasks.

What do they do if system goes down and unable to process user tasks?

Is there any solution like mysql has with event scheduler? Have anyone tried RabbitMQ to process various events?

Comment: Most questions about existing software, who uses, for what, etc., are off-topic here. This would be a good place to ask questions about how to develop software to fulfill their needs, not about what software already does so.

Answer (score 0):

CICS, COBOL and over-night batch jobs still abound.

Comment: But how do they process instant jobs, e.g one customer creates recurring payment at 3pm every monday, another one at 3.15 and so on. What technology is being used to process it realtime?

Comment: Many large institutions, with huge legacy systems. simply don't do that. My bank won't let me specify a regular payment at a time, only by day - I know of no UK bank that allows payment times to be specified. Indeed it's only very recently that UK banks have moved to on-the-same-day payments.

Answer (score 0):

Banks and telecom sector have very power full system and they are just develop for this specific purpose we just need to integrate them.
When i was working in a telecom company they have lot of servers and all of them have 32+GB of ram etc.

For banks they also have very power full system, When ever their system crash automatically other server start working. Banks have central repository  where they save their data due to the central system they didn't get data consistency issue.